# How to add url text file to string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a text file(not a local file, it's URL Text File) with 1 sentence and save it  as a string ,
Can someone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Elaborate your question.

Comment: Try to add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might also want to read the [Stack Overflow question checklist by Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a HTTP Get request using `fetch` or `XmlHTTPRequest` and store the value into a variable as a string

```
  var someVar;
  fetch('<path to text file>')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(sentence) {
    someVar = sentence;
  });
```

refer [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch ]
or [ https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp ]

Comment: When trying to see if the value is in the someVar i get "undefined"